# How do I pass an onclick argument to a CFC to update the database through AJAX?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfc

New to Ajax. Just trying to do a simple ajax/cfc vote yes/no app. Can’t get it to work

What I am trying to accomplish is a simple Vote "Yes or No" app where it shows the number of votes cast next to each link.  For example:

- **Yes** *(882 votes)*
- **No** *(163 votes)*.

When a visitor votes, the database should be updated with the vote and record the voter in a different table (so they can't vote again). Finally, a confirmation message is displayed with the new vote count:

- You voted **"Yes"** *(883 votes)* or
- You voted **No** *(164 votes)*

Now I had everything working but updating the database. I tried reworking the JavaScript (AJAX) to call a CFC by adding `($.ajax)` and moving the response messages within the ajax part. However, now it’s not working at all.  What did I do wrong?

Below is the new code I came up with. To keep this question simple, I am just showing the "No" Vote portion. Am I on the right track? This seem like it would be very simple.

**Voting link**

```
<A HREF="javascript:()" onclick="VoteNoID('#IdeaID#');">
   <SPAN ID="VoteNoMessage">No</SPAN>
</A> 
- <SPAN ID="NewNoCount">#NoCount#</SPAN>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script  LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
   function VoteNoID()  
    {  
     var VoteNoDescription = document.getElementById("VoteNoDescription").style.display='none';  
            $.ajax({   
                type: "POST",   
                url: "../CFC/VoteNo.cfc?method=VoteNoID",   
                data: recordata,   
                dataType: "html",   
                success: function(message) {   
                    $('#VoteNoMessage').html("you voted No");  
                    $('#NewNoCount').html("#NewCount#");  
                    }   
                });   
            });   
        } `     
<script>
```

**VoteNo.cfc**

```
<cffunction name="NoVote" access="remote" returntype="string" 
    <cfargument name="VoteNo" type="string" required="yes">
    <CFQUERY NAME="NoCountCK" DATASOURCE="MyDSN">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Ideas
        WHERE   IdeaID = #arguments.VoteNo#
    </CFQUERY>
    <CFSET NewCount=#NoCountCK.NoCount#+1>
    <CFQUERY NAME="UpdateNoCount" DATASOURCE="MyDSN">
        UPDATE  Ideas
        SET     NoCount = #NewCount#
        WHERE   IdeaID = #arguments.VoteNo#
    </CFQUERY>
    <CFQUERY NAME="MemberVote" DATASOURCE="MyDSN">
        INSERT INTO MemberVoteRecord(IdeaID,MemberID,DatePosted,YesNo)
        VALUES(#arguments.VoteNo#,#COOKIE.Member_ID#,#NOW()#,N)
    </CFQUERY>
    <cfreturn NewCount>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: what's not working?  Please help us to help you.

Comment: Basically it’s not updating the database or passing the 3 messages back to change the vote status. The old code would at least update the messages and close the description. Giving the appearance that a vote was cast, but not update the database.

Answer (score 0):

The success part of our .ajax() call is just setting the html to be the variable #newcount#. I'm not sure where that variable is being set initially, but if you would look at your raw html generated, you will see that the raw html contains a static number here. You need to set this as a javascript variable, not a  ColdFusion variable.

So, try setting this variable to be message, which is the argument passed to your success call back. Message should be equal to whatever your CFC is returning. I.e. if you would call the CFC directly in the browser, this is what your browser would render.

```
success: function(message) {   
        $('#VoteNoMessage').html("you voted No");  
            $('#NewNoCount').html(**message**);  
           }
```

Also, you'll want to adjust your CFC function's return format to be "plain". .